# CSS анимация изменяет положение элемента

Tags: css, html5, css3, svg, css-animation

У меня есть шестиугольник внутри окружности.

Посмотрите первоначальный сценарий: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njzwfvpf/)

Теперь я хочу, добавить анимацию вращения шестигранника внутри круга на `360deg`.

Здесь существующий сценарий с CSS анимацией ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp3y0fpz/))

```css
.rotate {
  -webkit-animation: rotating 3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
          animation: rotating 3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="350" height="350">
  <svg width="350" height="350">
    <circle cx="230.00591443779982" cy="155.55555555555554" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="100" cy="155.55555555555554" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="180.41237113402062" cy="155.55555555555554" r="50" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="165.0943396226415" cy="120.27491408934708" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="165.0943396226415" cy="200" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 600 720" width="295" height="205">
      <g transform="translate(239, 370)" class="rotate">
        <path></path>
        <path d="M 175 0 L 326.55444566227675 87.50000000000001 L 326.55444566227675 262.5 L 175 350 L 23.445554337723223 262.5 L 23.44555433772325 87.49999999999999" style="opacity: 0.4; fill: black;"></path>
      </g>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 600 720" width="507.4" height="799.5">
        <g transform="translate(105, 395)">
          <path d="M 175 0 L 341.43489035165186 120.9220259843842 L 277.8624191511828 316.57797401561584 L 72.13758084881722 316.57797401561584 L 8.565109648348141 120.92202598438415" style="opacity: 0.4; fill: black;"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959506/css-animation-changes-the-element-position/39959739#39959739

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема, с которой  вы столкнулись, состоит в том, что вы применяете преобразование с помощью `CSS` `(rotate(360deg))`, а у вас уже есть трансформация на тот же элемент в SVG `(translate(239, 370))`.

Вы можете решить эту проблему двумя способами:

1. применять все трансформации с помощью CSS, так что вы полностью 
   можете контролировать анимацию с помощью CSS.
2. применить CSS анимацию на дочерний элемент (шестиугольник).

Ниже приведен пример того, как можно решить эту проблему  вторым способом:

```css
.rotate {
  -webkit-animation: rotating 3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
          animation: rotating 3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="350" height="350">
  <svg width="350" height="350">
    <circle cx="230.00591443779982" cy="155.55555555555554" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="100" cy="155.55555555555554" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="180.41237113402062" cy="155.55555555555554" r="50" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="165.0943396226415" cy="120.27491408934708" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="165.0943396226415" cy="200" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 600 720" width="295" height="205">
      <g transform="translate(239, 370)">
        <path></path>
        <path class="rotate" d="M 175 0 L 326.55444566227675 87.50000000000001 L 326.55444566227675 262.5 L 175 350 L 23.445554337723223 262.5 L 23.44555433772325 87.49999999999999" style="opacity: 0.4; fill: black;"></path>
      </g>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 600 720" width="507.4" height="799.5">
        <g transform="translate(105, 395)">
          <path d="M 175 0 L 341.43489035165186 120.9220259843842 L 277.8624191511828 316.57797401561584 L 72.13758084881722 316.57797401561584 L 8.565109648348141 120.92202598438415" style="opacity: 0.4; fill: black;"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Ответил: [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki)